# jQuery Selector for ID of programatically generated content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, I am experimenting with jQuery and I made this (btw sati means hours):
**UPDATED**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    window.sati = 1;
    $("#addSat").click(function(){
        var sat = window.sati;
        $('form#form1').append('<span class="hour' + sat + '"><span class="numHour">' + sat + '</span><input type="text" value="" name="subject"/><button type="button" class="down">&darr;</button><button type="button" class="up">&uarr;</button></span><br/>');
        window.sati+=1;
    });
    $("form#form1 > span[class^='hour'] > button").on("click",(function(){
        alert("!");
    }));
});
</script>
```

As you see I am dynamically adding fields to the form, and that works well. It is the second function that gives me problems. That should be selecting the up and down buttons in the generated form span input thingy. Could you tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Search for "event delegation".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IDs have to be unique, that's why your code fails on the second row.

Use classes instead.

Also, your click() function might be looking for an element that's not created yet. Use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead, it works with dynamically added content.

---

UPDATE

> So I am using classes now but it still doesn't work! `$("form#form1 > span[class^='hour'] > button").on("click",(function(){ alert("!"); }));`

You needed to fix your on() selector:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    window.sati = 1;
    $("#addSat").click(function(){
        var sat = window.sati;
        $('form#form1').append('<span class="hour' + sat + '"><span class="numHour">' + sat + '</span><input type="text" value="" name="subject"/><button type="button" class="down">&darr;</button><button type="button" class="up">&uarr;</button></span><br/>');
        window.sati+=1;
    });
    $("form#form1").on("click", "span[class^='hour'] > button",function(){
        alert("!");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1"></form>
<button id="addSat">Dodaj Sat</button>
```

Comment: So I am using classes now but it still doesn't work!  `$("form#form1 > span[class^='hour'] > button").on("click",(function(){
  alert("!");
 }));`

Answer (score 0):

I created a working fiddle for you.

http://jsfiddle.net/8dtauh8e/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    window.sati = 1;
    $("#addSat").click(function(){
        var sat = window.sati;
        var item = $('<span class="hour' + sat + '"><span class="numHour">' + sat + '</span><input type="text" value="" name="subject"/><button type="button" class="down">&darr;</button><button type="button" class="up">&uarr;</button></span><br/>');

        $('form#form1').append(item);

        item.find('button').on('click', function(){
         alert('here - ' + $(this).prop('class') + ' ' + sat);
        });

        window.sati+=1;
    });
});
```